# Ways of making java api for C++ library?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'd like develop java api for one C++ library, the one way I can think of is JNI. But it looks like JNI has performance issue and this library is computing intensive, so I'd like to know is there any others to wrap C++ library as java api, thanks ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about JNA over JNI? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access and https://github.com/twall/jna check them out!

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative is to use JNA(Java Native Access)-https://github.com/twall/jna